# How do I print the fields queried?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am trying to get `bookTitle` and `author` from `Book`.

```
String hqlSelectBook = "select bookTitle,author from Book where bookID = " + bookIdList.get(size-1);
List<Object[]> tmp = sess.createQuery(hqlSelectBook).list();
```

Now how do I print each of the field ?

Comment: how do I print each of the field ?.. what do you ean by that

Comment: @StinePike I mean how do I print `book title` and `author`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to print.

```
List<Object[]> results = sess.createQuery(hqlSelectBook).list();

for (Object[] result : results) {
    String bookTitle = (String) result[0];
    String author = (String) result[1];
    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the doc of[Query.list()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#list%28%29)

> it returns the query results as a List. If the query contains multiple
>   results pre row, the results are returned in an instance of Object[].

So my guess is to iterate through each item on `list`. That will give you the row. Then in each element `object[0]` will give you `bookTitle` and `object[1]` will give the `author`. So cast them to `string` and use.

code wil be something like

```
for (int i = 0; i< tmp.size();i++) {
        System.out.prinln((String)(list.get(i)[0]));
        System.out.prinln((String)(list.get(i)[1]));   
}
```

**N.B.**.. I have no experience in hibernet. Answered this question from the basic.

Answer (score 0):

```
   for(Object[] i:temp){
       System.out.println("book title"+(String)i[0]);
       System.out.println("author"+(String)i[1]);
   }
```